# Why using a nonce not more than once in SSL/TLS

Tags: tls, stream-cipher, nonce

Why it is highly recommended to use a nonce once and only once in SSL/TLS? Same question with key streams in stream ciphers? What sort of attack(s) could take place if ever a nonce/key stream is used more than once? During the SSL/TLS handshake, is the client nonce/server nonce session related or connection related ?

Comment: Why downvoting my question?

Comment: Not sure… but it *could* be due to the fact we've got similar Q&As already handling your question. For example: [Nonces being used in SSL and MAC to prevent replay attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22433/12164), [Reuse nonce with Salsa20 stream cipher with counter](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43379/12164), [Repeated NONCE in CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39550/12164), [What happens if a nonce is reused in ChaCha20-Poly1305?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32075/12164), [Why do stream ciphers use a nonce?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30818/12164), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general, reusing a nonce enables replay attacks. This is a fundamental concept in authentication protocols.